Direct2D Clear/DrawBitmap Throwing Exception
In a C++ DLL I've got Direct2D initialized and then some draw functions. When calling pRenderTarget->Clear(...) it throws an AccessViolationException (Trying to access protected memory ...).
Here is the sample:
Initialize Direct2D
DLL_EXPORT void Direct2D_Init(HWND _hwnd, UINT width, UINT height)
{
    D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pD2DFactory);

    // Create WIC factory
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWICImagingFactory, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&g_pWICFactory));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // Handle error
        return;
    }

// Create a render target
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT, D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED));
    pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(props, D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(_hwnd, D2D1::SizeU(width, height)), &pRenderTarget);
}

// Exception is thrown when invoking this:
DLL_EXPORT void Direct2D_Clear()
{
    pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));
}

In the C# code, the invoke is done as such:
[DllImport(".\\d2dlib.dll")]
static extern void Direct2D_Clear();
        
public void Begin()
{
    if (renderOption == RenderOption.Direct2D)
    { 
        Direct2D_Clear(); // System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
    }
    else
        ...
}         

What might be going wrong? This seems unusual.
Minor Update
Running a drawing loop directly in C++ does not appear to have a problem. Here is what appears to work:
// The same init method as already displayed
Direct2D_Init(hWnd, 800, 600);
while (true)
{
    pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
    pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::CornflowerBlue));
    pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
}

^
This was rendered out onto a CreateWindow result
Outside of the context of a C# program though leads me to believe it may be how I'm writing the DLL. Both the DLL and C# program compile as x64. Or something about the PInvoke.

CreateHwndRenderTarget could be failing. I'd add a check. pRenderTarget being NULL or pointing to an indeterminate place seems a likely cause.

The Direct2D portion (D2D1CreateFactory + CreateHwndRenderTarget) works fine, so you're not showing the relevant code. Please post a reproducuble sample How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@RetiredNinja compelled me to look into window-creation solutions. So for sure it was working fine but since changing the project fundamentals it quit working until I found a different solution.

The problem resided in window creation as was suggested. When I was creating a WinForm window and using its handle, it would cause this exception. I found this out when applying this method instead to get a window:
if (RewBatch.renderOption == RenderOption.Direct2D || RewBatch.renderOption == RenderOption.Both)
{
    Process proc = Process.Start(".\\TestBed.exe");
    START:
    if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(Task.Delay(100));
        proc.Refresh();
        goto START;
    }
    Direct2D_InitEx(handle = proc.MainWindowHandle, (uint)window.Width, (uint)window.Height);
}

I created a CPP application with specific window dimensions and used that window's handle instead. This was a basic solution. I'm not exactly sure why the WinForms attempt stopped working, but I had been doing lots of updates to the sensitive code.
